# Could not launch “PRODUCT_NAME” on Xcode 12

Tags: ios, xcode, ios14, xcode12

I am using latest xcode 12 and try to run application on my device. getting error no such file or directory, I verified path of directory .app file exist on that path. For reference I am attaching image as well. Tried many solutions like, quit xcode and restart, remove user data but nothing works. Project working file before on xcode 11.7

xcode 12
device ios 14[image: Error detail]